# sql joining on same column with different values

Tags: mysql, sql

This is probably a simple sql question but was struggling...

Table 1 = matchInformation

homeTeamId,
  awayTeamId,
  etc

Table 2 = school:

id,
  name, 
  etc

I have a user selecting a "name" from the "school" table.  I would like to show all matchInformation data where team is either the homeTeam or awayTeam.  User should see names from the "school" table and not the ids from the matchInformation table.   **They should see both the school names, homeTeam and awayTeam.**

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add sample input and output in your question ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you've already answered this yourself, I want to provide an alternate method, joining the school table twice.

```
 Select hteam.name as hometeamname,
            ateam.name as awayteamname,
            mi.homeTeam,
            mi.awayTeam
 From matchInformation mi 
 Inner Join school hteam
         On hteam.ncaaId = mi.homeTeam
 Inner Join school ateam
         On ateam.ncaaId = mi.awayTeam
 Where hteam.name = 'FOO' Or ateam.name='FOO'
```

Comment: Thanks.  This was more like what I had hoped to figure out in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure if I just misunderstood your DB structure, but this is what it should look like.

```
SELECT  SC.schoolName, MA.homeTeamName, MA.awayTeamName
FROM    matchInformation MA

INNER JOIN
school SC ON SC.id = MA.schoolFSID

WHERE
MA.matchId = SC.matchFSID
```

You need to be able to identify the match and the school with a unique ID. This is what made me think about this for so long. You're trying to get the names of those teams even though you really don't know the context. What school is it? You have to have a `schoolFSID` in your `matchInformation` Table. What match is it? You need to have a `matchFSID` in your school table. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
SELECT school.name,mi.homeTeamId,mi.awayTeamId
FROM matchinformation mi
INNER JOIN  school on school.id = mi.homeTeamId or school.id= mi.awayTeamId
 where <condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that worked in the end.  I realize column names are a bit different but I wanted to simplify them in my initial question:

```
SELECT 
     (Select name 
        From school 
       Where mi.homeTeam=ncaaId) 
          As "Home Team",
    (Select name 
       From school 
      Where mi.awayTeam=ncaaId) 
         As "Away Team",
             mi.homeTeam, mi.awayTeam 
       From matchInformation 
         As mi 
 Inner Join school 
         As s
         On (s.ncaaId = mi.homeTeam OR s.ncaaId = mi.awayTeam)
      Where s.name = "FOO";
```

Comment: There is no way that anyone could guess from your question that this is the required format of the result